# Calcite SQL parser -- SELECT statement root node type not always SqlSelect

Tags: apache-calcite

I have a simple application that does text substitution on literals in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement. I run SqlParser.parseQuery() and apply .getWhere() to the result.

However, for the following query the root node is not an SqlSelect, but an SqlOrderBy:

```
select EventID, Subject
from WorkOrder
where OwnerID = 100 and Active = 1 and Type = 2
order by Subject
```

If we use "group by" instead of "order by" then the root is an SqlSelect as expected.

Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is intended. `ORDER BY` is not really a clause of `SELECT`. Consider

```
SELECT deptno FROM Emp
UNION
SELECT deptno FROM Dept
ORDER BY 1
```

The `ORDER BY` clause applies to the whole `UNION`, not to the second `SELECT`. Therefore we made it a standalone node.

When you ask Calcite to parse a query, the top-level nodes returned can be a `SqlSelect` (`SELECT`), `SqlOrderBy` (`ORDER BY`), `SqlBasicCall` (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT` or `VALUES`) or `SqlWith` (`WITH`).